# Format jqPlot point labels like: number (percent)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqplot

this is my first question.

I need to format a jqPlot chart point labels like this: 50 (100%)
Formating number and show percentage.

```
var s1 = [32, 28, 18, 6];

var ticks = ['0-20 kph', '21-40 kph', '41-60 kph', '61+ kph'];

plot1 = $.jqplot('bar-graph', [s1], {
    animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
    title: 'Gráficos de velocidade',
    captureRightClick: true,
    seriesColors: ['green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red'],
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        pointLabels: {
            show: true,
            formatString: '%s (?%%)' 
        },
        rendererOptions: {
            varyBarColor: true
        }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: ticks
        }
    },
    highlighter: {
        show: false
    }
});
```

On jsFinddle: http://jsfiddle.net/evandroprogram/r3PUE/10/

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can probably implement a function which returns a proper format string instead of setting the format explicitly. Something like this:

```
formatString: function(){return '%s (100%)';}()
```

You can do your calculations inside that function to come up with the appropriate string.

Comment: Perfect. But, now, I have another problem.
How to get the value from '%s'?
I used:
formatString: function() {return '%s (' + ('%s' / totalMarkers * 100) + '%%)';}()

Comment: You need a custom formatter. I have made some changes in the jsfiddle you set up, go try that. Rounding up of the percentage values are left to you.

EDIT: that fiddle didn't get saved, sorry. So here's the code for the formatter. Put this before the document ready call.

(function($) { 
    $.jqplot.LabelFormatter = function(format, val){
        return val + '(' + (val / totalMarkers * 100) + '%';
    };
})(jQuery);

Then use the following:
pointLabels: {
                show: true,
                formatString: '%s (%%)', 
                formatter: $.jqplot.LabelFormatter
            },

Comment: Man, thank you very much... I read about it, but, I tryed to use wrong. Sorry for my english, I am brazilian. All works perfectly. Good job.

Comment: +1 nice answer. Thanks very much for showing the code. Could you add the code from your comment to your answer it will make it much easier to read. For those wanting to see it quickly in action, I made a jsfiddle that shows what it does http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/42TDs/